# Mostrar un campo considerando el 10% de otra columna usando SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

Quisiera que me ayudaran con esta consulta, quiero que los costos que son mayor a 1000 me los muestre en otra columna aumentado al 10%.

Al momento solo tengo:

```
SELECT * FROM tarifa
```

El resultado es el siguiente:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Espero que me puedan ayudar.

Comment: Por favor [edit] tu pregunta explicando mejor a qué te refieres con: `me los muestre en otra columna aumentado al 10%`.

Comment: quiero mostrar en otra columna los precios mayores a 1000 aumentado en 10% usando el if

Comment: a lo que entiendo muestras los datos de una consulta en tu tabla y solo los que sean mayor a 1000 quieres que muestre el resultado en otra celda y el contenido sea mas grande es correcto ?

Comment: Podrías además publicar tu consulta cómo texto, y no como imagen? Gracias

Comment: Tengo columna con varios precios y quiero hacer con una consulta para que me muestre en otra columna los precios mayores a 1000 si no pasa los 1000 que me mustre el mismo precio

Comment: Hola Renzo, bienvenido a [es.so]. Justo como lo dice sstan, el título de la pregunta debe estar relacionado con su contenido, además, para futuras preguntas evita el uso de imágenes y pon directamente el código, esto nos puede ayudar a darte una respuesta más puntual a tu problema. Por esta ocasión he editado tu pregunta. De igual forma te recomiendo tomar el [recorrido](http://es.stackoverflow.com/tour) así como revisar el [centro de ayuda](http://es.stackoverflow.com/help) por si llegaras a tener alguna duda al respecto del sitio :)

Comment: gracias , es la primera vez que entro a esta pagina todavía no se muy bien como publicar

Answer (score 2):

Supongo que cuando dices que los costos sean mayores de 1000 te refieres a que el precio + impuesto sean mayores de 1000. El siguiente código te muestra el precio total más el 10% de su valor de los resultados cuyos precios + tarifas sean mayores de 1000 y los muestra en una tabla llamada "Precio_Total"

```
SELECT (1.10*precio) AS "Precio_Total" FROM tarifas where (precio + impuesto)> 1000
```

Si el costo es simplemente el precio sin sumarle el impuesto el código sería el siguiente:

```
SELECT (1.10*precio) AS "Precio_Total" FROM tarifas where precio > 1000
```

No hace falta que hagas uso de Transact SQL (uso de `if`/`else`, por ejemplo) para mostrar los resultados.

Answer (score 2):

Si cuando te refieres a costo haces referencia a la columna precio, la solución es la siguiente consulta:

```
SELECT idtarifa
    ,clase
    ,precio
    ,impuesto
    ,CASE 
        WHEN precio > 1000
            THEN precio * 1.1
        ELSE precio
        END preciomasel10
FROM tarifa
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Buena respuesta. Ajusté la consulta para que la condición sea tal como la pide OP, o sea mayor a 1000 en vez de 100. El problemita es que la imagen del resultado ya no corresponde a la consulta.